# Pymongo not able to connect to the database: pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to read the collection through pymongo but I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/GSingh/PycharmProjects/MC/quizQuestionAnswers.py", line 21,
>   in 
>       pprint.pprint(posts.find_one())   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py",
>   line 1262, in find_one
>       for result in cursor.limit(-1):   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py",
>   line 1189, in next
>       if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py",
>   line 1087, in _refresh
>       self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()   File
>   "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py",
>   line 1558, in _ensure_session
>       return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py",
>   line 1511, in __start_session
>       server_session = self._get_server_session()   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py",
>   line 1544, in _get_server_session
>       return self._topology.get_server_session()   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py",
>   line 427, in get_server_session
>       None)   File "C:\Users\GSingh\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py",
>   line 199, in _select_servers_loop
>       self._error_message(selector)) pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed

Following is the code I am running:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

username = 'username'
password = 'Password'

uri = "mongodb://"+username+":"+password+"@mc-*****.mongodb.net:27017/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256"
client = MongoClient(uri)
database = client["sws-quiz"]
collection = database["attempts"]

try:
    posts = database.posts
    pprint.pprint(posts.find_one())

finally:
    client.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It was because I did not do ssl=True